# Error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String; cannot be cast to

Tags: java, netbeans

No entiendo porque el error, ayuda porfavor.

```
public ArrayList EvaluarPatronFiguras(Image Imagen)
{
    ArrayList ListaResultadoRegiones = new ArrayList();
    aImagen=Imagen;
    //convirtiendo imagen a matriz
    CmatrizTransformacion oTransformador=new CmatrizTransformacion();
    String[][] MatrizImagen=oTransformador.ObtenerMatrizPatron(aImagen);

    CConversion conversor = new CConversion();
    BufferedImage imagenB = conversor.Convertir_Buffer(aImagen);

    oTransformador.Graficar(MatrizImagen);
    //obtener la lista de subregiones
    CAgrupar oGenerarGrup=new CAgrupar();
    ArrayList ListaGrupos = oGenerarGrup.GererarListaGrupos(MatrizImagen, "1");

    //evaluar Cada region dela figura
    int NroRegiones = ListaGrupos.size();
    for(int i=0;i<NroRegiones;i++)
    {

       CRegion SubRegioni;
       SubRegioni = (CRegion) ListaGrupos.get(i);


        double[] Resultadoi=EvaluarRegionFiguraPatron(SubRegioni.getaRegion());
        ListaResultadoRegiones.add(Resultadoi);

        ConstruirImagen(imagenB, SubRegioni.getaPosIx(), SubRegioni.getaPosIy(), SubRegioni.getaPosFx(), SubRegioni.getaPosFy());
    }
    return ListaResultadoRegiones;

}
```

La linea que me da error es la que dice SubRegioni = (CRegion) ListaGrupos.get(i);

Comment: Que tipo de dato retorna `oGenerarGrup.GererarListaGrupos`?

Answer (score 2):

Podrias tener un problema con el tipo definido para ListaGrupos, revisa eso:

```
ArrayList ListaGrupos = oGenerarGrup.GererarListaGrupos(MatrizImagen, "1");
```

Deberia ser:

```
 ArrayList<CRegion> ListaGrupos = oGenerarGrup.GererarListaGrupos(MatrizImagen, "1");
```

Y la funcion "oGenerarGrup.GererarListaGrupos":

```
function ArrayList<CRegion> GererarListaGrupos(....){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) No se que hace el método oGenerarGrup.GererarListaGrupos(..) pero debes analizar el retorno de ese método para ver si hay algún error.

2) La clase CRegion es un objeto que no se que atributos tiene, puede que solo tenga uno sin embargo ListaGrupos.get(i) esta retornando un String no algo que pueda mapearse como un CRegion.java.

3) Acabo de darme cuenta que MatrizImagen es un String[][] y puede que el método oTransformador.Graficar(MatrizImagen) no esté funcionando correctamente.

Creo que la pregunta sigue muy abierta pueden ser muchas razones las que lanzan ese error pero básicamente te esta diciendo que el String ListaGrupos.get(i) no se puede castear como un CRegion.java